# angularJS + Codeigniter Internal Server Error 500 on reload page

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter

I using angularJs for frontend and Codeigniter for the backend.

After activate `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`, when reload the page get `500 Internal Server Error`

Codeigniter is in `root/codeigniter` and on the root is angularJs

Here are my settings:

routing.js

```
 app.config( [ '$routeProvider' , '$httpProvider', '$locationProvider', function( $routeProvider , 
       $httpProvider, $locationProvider ) {


   $routeProvider.when( '/home',{
    templateUrl: 'page/home.html'
})

$routeProvider.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/home'
});

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

In root/index.html I put the `<base href="/" />` in `<head>` tag and remove `#` from all navigation link. And everything works well. But when I refresh or reload the page I get the error.

I use openserver on windows 10 and `.htassess` file on root looks like this:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This is problem of CI routing ? you need to handle all type of routes redirect to your base url.

Comment: In CI I do not use the routes. Need to create?

Comment: Yes you need this : https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html